# Access Web App query 3 Tables with aggregatios - Need a workaround

Tags: database-design, join, ms-access, aggregate

I'm designing an Access 2016 Web App for inventoring our computers.

The problem I have is with a query where I want to get the CPUCore-amount and RAM-Amount for each PC.

[image: GUI-Query]

The computer-value in RAM and CPU are lookups on Computer.DNS
So in SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT Computer.DNS,SUM(CPU.Cores),SUM(RAM.Size) FROM Computer,CPU,RAM GROUP BY Computer.DNS
```

The result from the GUI-Query aboth is

[![Result2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sljrw.png)

Both SUM coloumns are (for most PCs) wrong.

The formula it's using (which are wrong!):

```
Cores: COUNT(CPUs)       * realAmount

RAM  : COUNT(RAM-sticks) * realAmount
```

Can anybody show me why it's doing that and what I did wrong?

I tried using

```
Cores: Sum([CPU].[Cores]-Count([RAM].[Size]))
```

in the "Field"-field but I get the error "Cannot have aggregate function in expression"

---

I have one workaround going which is making a seperate query for each 1:n-relation which connects DNS and SUM(foo) and one query which has the results of all the queries. Then in the little ERM for the query I connect every DNS entry of the queries.
For 1:1 relations in the DB I can just use the standard table in the overallQuery.

still looking for other workarounds though

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a Cartesian product (or cross join) between the tables,  which means that you are "assigning" all cpus and all ram to all computers.

You need to restrict the join with a where clause like:

```
SELECT Computer.DNS,SUM(CPU.Cores),SUM(RAM.Size) 
FROM Computer,CPU,RAM
WHERE Computer.id = CPU.computer
  AND Computer.id = RAM.computer 
GROUP BY Computer.DNS
```

so that each computer relates only to it's ram and it's cpu's.

IMO it is much clearer if you do it with an ANSI JOIN instead:

```
SELECT Computer.DNS,SUM(CPU.Cores),SUM(RAM.Size) 
FROM Computer
JOIN CPU
    ON Computer.id = CPU.computer
JOIN RAM
    ON Computer.id = RAM.computer  
GROUP BY Computer.DNS
```

You may also use an alias for the tables which makes it a bit shorter:

```
SELECT c.DNS, SUM(CP.Cores), SUM(R.Size) 
FROM Computer as c
JOIN CPU as cp
    ON c.id = cp.computer
JOIN RAM as r
    ON c.id = r.computer  
GROUP BY c.DNS
```